# MySQL import data from SQL Server export file

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, data-import

I need to import into a MySQL database some data that has previously been exported from a SQL Server 2008 database.

The SQL Server export has been made into a SQL file, and export file format looks like this:

```
INSERT [table1] ([column1], [column2], [column3]) VALUES (1351801, 1548565, N'/*******************************************************************************
 *
 *******************************************************************************/

package chap1;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("lala");
    }
}
')
INSERT [table_name] ([column1], [column2], [column3]) VALUES (1351851, 154865, N'/*******************************************************************************
 *
 *******************************************************************************/

package chap2;

public class Implementation1 implements Interface1 {

    @Override
    public void go() {
    }

}
')
```

Note that `column3` contains some Java Source code.

I try to load this data into MySQL using the command:

```
source table1_export.sql;
```

Of course, I have noticed that this is not MySQL insert syntax and I have tried to change this to the correct MySQL syntax. But, this also fails when loading the data for `column3`, which contains Java code and could have some special characters that MySQL doesn't like.

Any of what I can do to load the data from the file into MySQL?

Comment: You might want to abandon the export file and try http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/ to do a direct migration.

Answer (score 1):

Using Mysql Import Service you can achieve this easily from a .sql database dump file.

```
String jdbcConnectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabaseName?useSSL=false";

try {
            String sql = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("your .sql dump file path")));
            MysqlImportService service = MysqlImportService.builder()
                .setDatabase(databaseName)
                .setSqlString(sql)
                .setUsername('your database username)
                .setPassword('your database password')
                .setDeleteExisting(true)
                .setDropExisting(true)
                .setJdbcDriver(configuration.getDriver())
                .setJdbcConnString(jdbcConnectionUrl).build();
            service .importDatabase();
        }
        catch (IOException | SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
```